# Detect URL valid for iOS

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I want to detect if the `URL` is valid. So I see the following function.

```
+ (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString
```

As the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) said, an `NSURL` object initialized with `URLString`. If the `string` was malformed, returns `nil`. But actually, I call `URLWithString` with any `string`, it will return not `nil`. This documentation is wrong? 
And could you provide a workaround to detect if `URL` is valid?

Comment: A huge amount depends on what exactly you mean here by "valid". Apple's documentation is pretty explicit in pointing out the RFCs they use to determine validity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation isn't wrong - `NSURL` supports both absolute and relative URLs. Additionally, it's not just used to remote (web) URLs, but for local file URLs as well. For example:

```
// Totally valid NSURL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];

// Just as valid NSURL
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"2rwehrfuiw34twef"];
```

You don't get any guarantees that the URL is reachable. It does guarantee you URL complies with RFC 2396. If you want to check that a URL is available you can either use the `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` method (which is available from iOS 5 onwards, but should *only* be used for file path URLs) or make a network request for it (which you'll have to do if your URL isn't a file path).

Comment: You might want to look into [NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:] as well, since it does a preflight evaluation, saving some time and being synchronous.